# When a past participle is at the beginning of a sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

In this line,

> "Asked why a non­specialist can be entrusted with such work, a local
> oﬃcial praises foreign ­ministry volunteers for their promotional
> skills"

I suppose maybe the writer means *When he was asked why*.. perhaps something was omitted and the verb **asked** was therefore at the beginning, what do you called this kind of "omission" grammatically?

Comment: It's not necessarily helpful to assume the word ***when*** is "missing" in such contexts. It's just a Past Participle used adverbially / adjectivally. No different to, say, ***Grief-stricken** by the death of his wife, he moved back to his homeland*. The precise nature of the relationship between that "fronted" adverbial element and the main clause that follows is context-specific. It might effectively be something corresponding to ***when***, but it might be ***if***, or ***because***, or any of several other prepositions / conjunctions.

Comment: ...note that *exactly* the same situation arises with ***continuous*** participles as well as ***past*** participles. For example, ***Seeking publicity for his department**, a local oﬃcial praises foreign ­ministry volunteers for their promotional skills*.

Comment: (Though one could argue—perhaps a bit hair-splittingly—that an adverbial participle does always imply a "when" or "while." "He ran out of the haunted house, scared to death": he ran *while* scared. "Drunk driving" is driving *while* drunk. (Well, ok—"he drove drunk," there, now it's adverbial. :-) )