# Can we use the verb "remember" in progressive tense?

Tags: progressive-aspect

Is this sentence correct or not:

> What were you thinking about?
> I ***was remembering*** my wedding day.

*(Example sentence from "understanding and using English Grammar" page 19)*

Comment: Yes, we can use the verb "remember" in the past progressive. The meaning shifts slightly. "Just then I remembered that I left the stove on"—something popped into my head at one point in time. "I was gazing out the window, remembering past years"—I was spending a period of time dwelling on memories.

Comment: I found the earlier question [Does "He started remembering" breach the laws of english grammar?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/182931/does-he-started-remembering-breach-the-laws-of-english-grammar) which *in principle* this question should be a duplicate of. But I'm not impressed with the answer to that earlier question - it's exceptionally long, but contains less useful information than @AndyBonner's comment here.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @FumbleFingers I see what you mean. There were specific questions packed into that earlier one that got addressed, and diluted the basic issue of state vs instance. One of these days I'll start a Meta question about "If a questioner finds a near-duplicate that *almost* expresses what they want to ask, how invasively can they edit it to bend it to their purpose?"

Comment: @AndyBonner: Imho the *best* way to address this situation would be if you posted an additional answer on the earlier question (and ping me in a comment so I can go and upvote it! :). ***In principle*** a few tweaks to your existing comment here could convert it into an Answer that adequately addresses both questions. But I won't nag you about it - I know that ***in practice*** it often takes a lot more effort to post an answer than an equally informative comment.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Lol, I just restrained myself from nagging you to turn [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/301649/when-a-past-participle-is-at-the-beginning-of-a-sentence) beautifully substantive double-decker comment into an answer! (Though maybe you had the same problem I had—what *do* you call such omission?)

Comment: @AndyBonner: It might get confusing spanning our comments across two different but relevant Questions here! But whereas I'm now inclined to agree with you that *an adverbial participle [might?] always imply a "when" or "while*, I'm not convinced that justifies claiming that some such term is being "omitted" if it's not explicitly present. That seems a bit like claiming that the word ***actually*** is "omitted" in my preceding sentence here, simply because it *could* have been included (and / or the meaning thereof is "contextually implied").